# Automation script acting very slow on browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new in learning Java Selenium. Whenever I try to run a script, the browser loads for a long time and then gives displays the site which I'm testing. I'm seeing this recently only. Writing more scripts make even more slower.

Here is the sample code I just worked on. If someone knows the issue, please help.

```
System.setProperty("webriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\AM00773329\\Desktop\\TestDriver\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions ChromeT = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeT.setBinary("C:\\Users\\AM00773329\\Desktop\\TestDriver\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe");
driver.get("http://qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
WebElement footer = driver.findElement(By.id("gf-BIG"));
WebElement footerSub = footer.findElement(By.xpath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul"));
System.out.println(footerSub.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());
```

Comment: where do you initialize the webdriver?  (new Chromedriver(ChromeT);?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons why your Selenium browser is loading slowly:

Your computer or network may be slow. Selenium is a resource-intensive application, so it needs a fast computer and network connection to run smoothly.
Your Selenium script may be inefficient. If your script is too complex or uses inefficient locators, it will take longer to run.
The website you are testing may be slow. If the website is complex or has a lot of traffic, it will take longer to load.
Here are some tips for speeding up your Selenium scripts:

Use efficient locators. CSS selectors are generally faster than XPath selectors.
Avoid unnecessary interactions with the browser. For example, if you only need to read the text of an element, don't click on it first.
Use implicit waits instead of explicit waits. Implicit waits are more efficient, especially for scripts that interact with multiple elements on a page.
Use a headless browser. Headless browsers run without a GUI, which can improve performance.
Use a Selenium Grid. A Selenium Grid allows you to distribute your tests across multiple machines, which can significantly improve performance.
Here are some specific things you can check in your sample code:

Make sure you are using the latest version of the ChromeDriver. Older versions of the ChromeDriver may be slower.
Try disabling extensions in your Chrome browser. Some extensions can slow down the browser.
Try using a headless browser. You can do this by setting the headless option to true in your ChromeOptions object.
Try using a Selenium Grid. This is more complex to set up, but it can significantly improve performance